# Is there a dangling pointer problem in this code?

Tags: c++, pointers, c-str

```
string str;    
char *a=str.c_str();
```

This code is working fine for me but every place else I see this code instead

```
string str;
char *a=new char[str.length()];
strcpy(a,str.c_str());
```

I wonder which one is correct and why?

Comment: What is `str`? If `str` is `std::string`, neither of them are correct.

Comment: "This code is working fine for me" - try turning on compiler warnings!

Comment: The big question is why would someone write code like that (the second snippet)?  This is even if the correct number of characters is used in the `new[]` call.  It's like the author is begging for a memory leak to occur somewhere.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: You see it a fair bit when working with APIs that take a `char*` as input, even if they purportedly don't modify the buffer.

Comment: I learned to use `std::vector<char>` for that.

Comment: Be careful because `std::vector` don't automatically add null character at end of the "strings".

Comment: In the very limited context provided, the two snippets do not have a dangling pointer problem.  There may be dangling pointer problems elsewhere, in the code not provided.  A [mcve] would be helpful to properly answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two code segments do different things.

The first assigns the **pointer value** of `str` to your new c-tpye string, and implicitly converts from `const char*`(c_str() return type) to `char*`, which is wrong. If you were to change your new string you would face an error. Even if `c_str()` returned `char*`, altering the new string would also make changes in `str`.

The second on the other hand creates a new c-type string from the original string, copying it byte-by-byte to the new memory allocated for your new string.
Although the line of code you wrote is incorrect, as it does not cover the terminating null character of a c-type string `\0`. In order to fix that, allocate 1 extra byte for it:

```
char *a=new char[str.length()+1];
```

After copying the data from the first string to your new one, making alterations to it will not result in changes in the original `str`.

Comment: So does it mean that c_str() just returns back the address where the char array for string class is stored (and thus it has to mark it const, so that we don't mess with it)?

Comment: @Saqib Exactly. You can use that pointer to offset the character array using pointer arithmetics, but you shan't treat it as a primitive type for assignment. Further read on Pointer Semantics to be clear on what you can and cannot do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the type of `str` is `std::string`, neither of the code is are correct.

```
char *a=str.c_str();
```

is invalid because `c_str()` will return `const char*` and removing `const` without casting (usually `const_cast`) is invalid.

```
char *a=new char[str.length()];
strcpy(a,str.c_str());
```

is invalid because `str.length()` don't count the terminating null-character while allocating for terminating null-character is required to use `strcpy()`.

There are no dangling pointer problem in code posted here because no pointers are invalidated here.

Comment: Note that std::string::length doesn't traverse the string - the standard requires it is O(1). It's possible the string contains 0 values in its buffer. `strcpy` would stop at the first 0 in `str`. Hence the behaviour is not necessarily undefined, depending on how `str` is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly.

Consider this.

```
char const* get_string() {
    string str{"Hello"};    
    return str.c_str();
}
```

That function returns a pointer to the internal value of `str`, which goes out of scope when the function returns. You have a dangling pointer. Undefined behaviour. Watch out for time-travelling nasal monkeys.

Now consider this.

```
char const* get_string() {
    string str{"Hello"};
    char const* a = new char[str.length()+1];
    strcpy(a, str.c_str());
    return a;
}
```

That function returns a valid pointer to a valid null-terminated C-style string. No dangling pointer. If you forget to `delete[]` it you will have a memory leak, but that's not what you asked about.

The difference is one of object lifetime. Be aware of scope.